# Contextual Menu Plugin for Browsing Folder (or disk) Contents By Right Clicking?

Tags: finder, shortcut-menu

The title of this post is pretty on-the-money but I'll try to elaborate some anyway. I'm looking for a contextual menu plugin for Mac that will let me browse the contents of any folder or folder like object in the Finder, through submenus, by right clicking on it.

I would envision this working by adding an addition item to the primary contextual menu, maybe an item called "Contents > " or "Browse > ", and mousing-over that item would put you in a full sub-menu tree of the contents. The same submenu tree you get from clicking on a folder in the dock (when you have View Contents set to Menu).

Comment: What would be the purpose/goal of using this? What would ou wan to happen once you are done navigating with the right mouse button?

Comment: It would be just like browsing the contents of a folder in the Dock, you would click on an item and open it. So if you clicked on a folder, it would open the folder. If you clicked on a file, it would open the file.

Comment: So like navigating in the Finder, basically? :-)

Comment: From that comment, I'm not sure if you get what I'm saying or not. Have you ever put a folder in your dock, set it's display mode to list, and then clicked on it to navigate it's contents through a series of submenus? That's the behavior I would love to have of any folder I right click on.

Comment: I‘ve set Finder to column mode, which IMHO is kind of similar. But I don‘t question your goal here, just tried to understand the context.

Comment: Column view has long been the primary Finder view mode I use.